# Como puedo enviar 2 formularios con 1 solo boton

Tags: javascript, php, html, formularios

Estoy tratando de enviar 2 formularios los cuales toman datos del usuario y otro usuario al cual le quiero dar un poder simple , en este ultimo tengo un boton el cual envia los datos y los muestra en un docuemnto pero los datos del primer formulario no los muestra .

```
<form id="formulario" class="border shadow row" method="post" action="apptramite.php">
          <br><br>
          <h4><b>Datos del solicitante</b></h4>
          <br><br>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
            <label for="name">Nombres</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombres" class="form-control" id="nombres" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="name">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
          </div>
        

          
          
          <br><br><br>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>


    <section>
      <div class="row col-lg-11 mt-5 mt-lg-0 d-flex align-text-left" style="margin-left: 60px; margin-right: 60px;">
        <form id="formulario2" class="border shadow row" method="post" action="apptramite.php">
          <br><br>
          <h4><b>Viene a conferir poder a:</b></h4>
          <br><br>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
            <label for="name">Nombres</label>
            <input type="text" name="nompoder" class="form-control" id="nompoder" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="name">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailpoder" id="emailpoder" required>
          </div>
          
          

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="name">Para los siguientes efectos:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Para los siguientes efectos:" id="textefectos" name="textefectos" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <br><br><br><br>
          <div class="section">
            <button name="botondatos" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('formulario').submit();" class="btn btn-primary contact aceptarButton text-bold">Continuar</button>
          </div>
          <br><br>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
```

espero me puedan ayudar para poder enviar esos 2 formularios con el mismo boton, trate de hacerlo con una funcion onclick y no me dio resultados.

Comment: Ya existe una respuesta a esta pregunta la puedes leer [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329721/hay-alguna-manera-de-enviar-dos-formularios-diferentes-con-un-solo-input-submit), es importante que investigues antes de realizar una pregunta puedes "Googlearlo" una vez que tengas la noción y te atores en algo haz una pregunta puntual.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Hay alguna manera de enviar dos formularios diferentes con un solo Input Submit?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329721/hay-alguna-manera-de-enviar-dos-formularios-diferentes-con-un-solo-input-submit)